# Specify outpath when downloading files from URL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, shutil

I have some files I am downloading from a url.

I can currently access my files like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

prefix = 'https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/MOST/MOD10A1.006/'
download_url = "https:/path_to_website"

s = requests.session()                                                         
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(download_url).text, "lxml")  

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

     final_link = os.path.join(prefix, a['href'])
     result = s.get(final_link, stream = True)
     with open(a['href'], 'wb') as out_file:
          shutil.copyfileobj(result.raw, out_file)
```

This will download the files fine and puts it into a default directory of C:/User.

I would like to choose where to download my files though. You can choose where the outpath is with `wget` but my method with that downloads empty files as if they aren't being accessed.

I tried this with `wget` like this:

```
out_path = "C:/my_path"
prefix = 'https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/MOST/MOD10A1.006/'

s = requests.session()                                                         
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(download_url).text, "lxml")  

for a in page.find_all('a', href=True):

     final_link = os.path.join(prefix, a['href'])
     download = wget.download(final_link, out = out_path)
```

I think wget isn't working because I am accessing the website with authentication (not shown), and when I join the final link I am no longer accessing it with authentication. Is there a way to specify the outpath with shutil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the first method, replacing the path of the file opened with `os.path.join(out_path, a['href'])` ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

out_path = "C:\\my_path"    
prefix = 'https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/MOST/MOD10A1.006/'
download_url = "https:/path_to_website"

s = requests.session()                                                         
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(download_url).text, "lxml")  

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
     final_link = os.path.join(prefix, a['href'])
     result = s.get(final_link, stream = True)
     new_file_path = os.path.join(out_path, a['href'])
     with open(new_file_path, 'wb') as out_file:    # this will create the new file at new_file_path
          shutil.copyfileobj(result.raw, out_file)
```

Comment: ahh, I see.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create target path like below,

```
target_path = r'c:\windows\temp'
with open(os.path.join(target_path, a['href']), 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(result.raw, out_file)
```